# AjaxFileUplaod not working on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jsajaxfileuploader

I use ajaxfileuplad , Before Uploading to Server I test it local it was working , after Uploading to server , I had an issue that the there is no error returned , but the folder still empty no image is uploaded ,

1. I check the permissions for the destination Folder ( IUSRS ,
   IIS_IUSRS ,etc ...)
2. the returned URL also correct that means
       Server path is working
3. I have added to web.config the Correct  Settings.

Control Code : `<cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="resetControl" MaximumNumberOfFiles="6" AllowedFileTypes="jpeg,jpg,gif,png" BackColor="#FC6810" ForeColor="White" runat="server" OnClientUploadStart="uploadStarted" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnUploadComplete="fileUploadComplete" />`
BehindCode :

```
 string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath("~/usergallery/");
    try
    {
        newfilename = Path.GetRandomFileName() + e.FileName;   AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadFolder + newfilename);

    }
    catch { }
```

Are there any extra Setting to look for ?

EDIT : 
ERROR : Uncaught error raising upload complete event and start new upload' this is the error 't.onreadystatechange  @ ScriptResource.axd?d=-9YDjdHizPInlZIfdnhPn8S7lpwKI_Y8guh‌​PydxMhsGoEDARRpAj9Eq4wYDzyMDF6zZSq3xA4TLhuv…:1 '

and Error on Server Side : Could not find a part of the path

Note that the Returned Path is Correct.

Comment: The reason you'ren not getting any errors is becasue of you're not catching them

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mywedfolder\usergallery\1wo2hxub.5eijanson.jpg'. this is what I got after removing the try catch , but the Path is correct.

Comment: 'Uncaught error raising upload complete event and start new upload' this is the error 't.onreadystatechange @ ScriptResource.axd?d=-9YDjdHizPInlZIfdnhPn8S7lpwKI_Y8guhPydxMhsGoEDARRpAj9Eq4wYDzyMDF6zZSq3xA4TLhuv…:1
'